# Anyone know what this graphic style is called or how to recreate it?

Tags: graphic-styles

The graphic style of the type kind of reminds me of the old HBO title sequence.

[image: Daphni Joli Mai]

Comment: something retro? like stranger things.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a specific name for that style, it is a mix of two main ideas:

1. Color Spectrum
2. Modern/Rave Design

I would suggest:

- Color Spectrum Wheel, recreate it and apply it as you wish.
- Swiss Style, look at the color overlaying.
- Use Rave Style Fonts and Placement